# Can a monkey recreate the work of Shakespeare by randomly hitting at a keyboard?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, feasibility

I am thinking of writing a program that will randomly generate a string of N characters, where N is the number of characters in book X, including spaces, proper punctuation and capitalization. During each random character generation, I will check if the output matches the actual text of book X.

Assuming that the English alphabet is used, with some sane grammar rules encoded into the generator, is it computationally feasible to write a program to randomly generate the text of book X?

What sort of optimizations can be implemented to make the problem an easier one to solve?

What sort of running time would you need using a modern quad-core (i5) desktop computer. How about using a super computer?

> In rough terms, each page of a standard-format hardcover book has
>   about 300-350 words, and each word is five characters plus a space. So
>   a typical book page has, say 1,500 to 1,800 characters (not counting
>   spaces.). If we consider 250 pages as standard book length, then
>   you're talking about maybe 400,000 characters if you don't count the
>   spaces; 500,000 if you do. [source](http://www.quora.com/Books/How-many-characters-of-text-letters-are-in-an-average-book)

So assuming that book X has 500,000 characters and that our alphabet is of size 30. Can one do any better than 30^500,000 ~(4.2 × 10^738560)?

Comment: I'm guessing this is NP-Hard, but since I don't have a real rationale behind that I'm going to leave this as a comment instead of a true answer. Good question though imo :)

Comment: Widely studied..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem_in_popular_culture

Comment: A single monkey? He'd probably die before he recreated the works of Shakespeare... :)

Comment: I'm very confused about this question; if the whole N-letter string is produced randomly (not just a permutation of a given set of letters, but a real random string over an alphabet), then there is no telling about the computation time; the first generated string might already be the text you want. On the other hand, with different probabilities you might need any finite amount of time until it is produced, always having a non-zero remaining probability of not terminating at all. Do you really mean generate random strings?

Comment: @G.Bach, to mimic the monkey, yes it would have to be random. But to make it a computationaly feasible problem, I've opted to go with the brute force method: "aaaaaaaa", "aaaaaaab", "aaaaaaaac", ...

Comment: @Ramin I still don't understand, how is that random if you're just listing all N-letter words in lexicographical order? I don't really understand what the problem you're trying to solve actually is.

Comment: @G.Bach, can a monkey recreate the works of Shakespeare? Since I don't have a monkey at my disposal, I will use a program to simulate a monkey randomly hitting keys on a keyboard. With computers you can either go in lexicographical order or by random N-length string generation. The former is the saner method. It's more of a thought experiment than an actual implementation. The current implementation I have in mind will take the best super computer longer to run then the estimated age of the universe, and by a huge factor.

Comment: I understand the thought experiment, but that's a mathematical question with a definitive answer. By altering the way you compute the string, you're answering a different question; for example, the lexicographical order generation will not tell you anything about randomness. (btw I don't think implementing either method is "sane".) I still don't understand what problem you're trying to solve: the "will the monkey type it?" is settled with "probability that he will converges to 1 with number of tries going to infinity", the question whether it appears in a lex. ordering of all strings is "yes".

Comment: Since my current method for implementing the monkey experiment in code is unfeasible, are there any "hacks" one can use to make it a feasible implementation? Granted that these hacks might defeat the purpose of the experiment. To rephrase the question, "is there any way for a computer to 'generate' the works of Shakespeare without actually knowing anything about the contents of the text beforehand in a feasible amount of time using a modern computer."

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an idea so crazy that nobody else has tried it, you're going to have to try harder :-) - see http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-15060310,,

A few million virtual monkeys are close to re-creating the complete works of Shakespeare by randomly mashing keys on virtual typewriters.

A running total of how well they are doing shows that the re-creation is 99.990% complete.

The first single work to be completed was the poem A Lover's Complaint.

Set up by US programmer Jesse Anderson the project co-ordinates the virtual monkeys sitting on Amazon's EC2 cloud computing system via a home PC.

(+ lots more info including practical experience with real monkeys)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a permutation of characters, you can model this as a permutation of words - most books use few if any novel words (exceptions being books like Lewis Carroll's "Through the Looking Glass" - you'd probably need to model the poem "Jabberwocky" as a permutation of characters).  In addition, most words in the dictionary aren't used in literature, so you can probably limit yourself to a dictionary of, say, the 10,000 most commonly used words and still account for most books.

Using a grammar to restrict the order of words is trickier, because a lot of books use illegal word orderings (especially in dialogue).  Maybe you could use a standard [English parser](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Parsers_for_English) for sentences that aren't in quotes (meaning non-dialogue) in order to filter out illegal word orderings, and then use a straight word permutation for sentences that are in quotes.  Obviously this won't work for a book like "Ulysses" where the laws of grammar get chucked out the window.

Comment: So the problem now becomes 10,000 ^ 75,000 = 1 × 10^300000. Seems a lot better.

Comment: @Ramin You can improve on that with a randomized algorithm: the top 100 English words account for 50% of all written words, so this becomes 100 ^ 37500 + 10000 ^ 37500

Comment: Better, but still not feasible. :)

Comment: It's not really increasing the odds, because you're only counting 10,000 words that make sense while leaving out 5,000,000,000 words that don't make sense. The monkey can't distinguish between the two, so might rethink your math.

Answer (score 0):

I would use  [genetic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) for this.